# Joining two sql tables and grouping

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables in my datebase:

Cars:
IdCar PK,
Company,
Type,
Color

Renting:
Id-rent_date PK,
IdCar FK,
Car_return_date

I need to write a query that will return three columns:
- Year
- amount of days in which cars of specific company was rented in the year
- Company - from Cars table

For now i have:

> SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, Id-rent_date, Car_return_date) AS Days, Company 
>   FROM Renting  INNER JOIN Cars ON Renting.IdCar = Cars.IdCar

I tried to group by Company in the end of query but it is returning an error:

Column 'Renting.Id-rent_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete query:

```
 declare @iter int
        declare @max int
        declare @test Table ([Id-rent_date] datetime, Car_return_date datetime, IdCar int)
        set @iter = 0
        select @max = max(year(Car_return_date) - year([Id-rent_date]))  FROM Renting

              WHILE(@iter < @max)
              BEGIN
          insert into @test 
                  SELECT 
            DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,[Id-rent_date]) + @iter, 0)
           ,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,[Id-rent_date]) + 1 + @iter, -1)
           ,IdCar
          FROM Renting
          where year([Id-rent_date]) + @iter <> year(Car_return_date) and year([Id-rent_date]) <> year(Car_return_date)
          set @iter = @iter + 1
              END
SELECT    YEAR([Id-rent_date]), SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, [Id-rent_date], Car_return_date)) AS Days, 
           Company 
FROM 

                  (SELECT 
            [Id-rent_date]
           ,[Car_return_date]
           ,IdCar
          FROM Renting
          where year([Id-rent_date]) = year(Car_return_date)
          union all
              SELECT 
            [Id-rent_date]
           ,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,[Id-rent_date]) + 1, -1)
           ,IdCar
          FROM Renting
          where year([Id-rent_date]) <> year(Car_return_date)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 
            DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,[Car_return_date]), 0)
           ,[Car_return_date]
           ,IdCar
          FROM Renting
          where year([Id-rent_date]) <> year(Car_return_date)
              UNION ALL
        select * from @test) RentingSplit inner join Cars ON RentingSplit.IdCar = Cars.IdCar
GROUP BY   Company, YEAR([Id-rent_date])
```

Comment: I didn't suppose that query will be so complicated! It is working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: if you allow in the field Car_return_date to value NULL (the car has not been returned) you should use ISNULL(Car_return_date,getdate()) instead of Car_return_date.
It should look like SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, [Id-rent_date], ISNULL(Car_return_date,getdate())))

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `group by` clause, all the items in the select list must either be the columns you've grouped by or aggregate calculations. Here, e.g., you want to sum the amount of days each company had:

```
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, Id-rent_date, Car_return_date)) AS Days, 
           Company 
FROM       Renting 
INNER JOIN Cars ON Renting.IdCar = Cars.IdCar
GROUP BY   Company
```

Comment: Great, this was thing that i missed, thanks! Now i have days of renting each company car, how can i separate it into years? Will be there needed some select inside another select or things like that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy because you have to consider the case in which year Id-rent_date is different from the Car_return_date.
If you assume that YEAR([Id-rent_date]) = YEAR(Car_return_date) is

```
SELECT    YEAR([Id-rent_date]), SUM(DATEDIFF(dd, [Id-rent_date], Car_return_date)) AS Days, 
           Company 
FROM       Renting 
INNER JOIN Cars ON Renting.IdCar = Cars.IdCar
GROUP BY   Company, YEAR([Id-rent_date])
```

Comment: Yes, this is a problem, i am considering that case, i executed the query: SELECT * FROM Renting WHERE YEAR(Id-rent_date) != YEAR(Car_return_date) to test how much data is related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the column name id-rent_date  to id_rent_date because - is a reserved character and then :

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(dd, Id_rent_date, Car_return_date) 
AS Days, 
DATEPART(yy, Car_return_date) 
AS year, Company 
FROM  Renting 
INNER JOIN Cars 
ON Renting.IdCar = Cars.IdCar
GROUP BY Company
```